# radio buttons doesn't remain checked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a code in `Visual Basic`(using visual studio 2010) and now I have this problem:

I put 3 `RadioButtons` in a form, I select a button and  go in another form (application has several forms).
The problem is that when I come back in first form that contains the `RadioButtons`(meaning,close the current form and show that form ), the buttons that I selected is no more selected, and I want to remain selected. What's the problem here? What I have to do?

Comment: How do you "come back" to the form?

Comment: There are plenty of reasons why the radio button can be deselected. We can't help you without additional information.

Comment: is a code for hang man game....and I use those buttons for chose difficulty of the game. I chose a button and throught another button(normal) I go in the main form (meniu). but if I acces again the form difficulty (where I have those radio buttons) those button that i selected previously is no more checked....i don't know i code to post here...cuz' i work more with buttons and forms.

Comment: show how you "come back" to the other form - if you are not instancing your forms explicitly, you might be showing a new instance of the old form.

Comment: I mean ...I don't wrote any code for this buttons...I have to write something?

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23660028/edit) your post to show how you "come back [to the] first form" so we can see what you are doing

Comment: "I got this situations with radio buttons" is not an informative title that will have any meaning to future readers when they see it in a search result. Please [edit] your question to something that provides information about what "situations" might be while you're adding information requested by others. Please **do not** add the information to comments - once again, [edit] your question to include the details there where they can easily be seen.

Comment: My bet is that you are recreating the form with `new` and expecting it to be the same instance as the previous time you showed it.

Comment: I solve the problem...sorry for your time and thanck's for trying to help me.....was my bad. I don't know how I was  so stupid:)
I wrote "Me.close" instead "Me.hide"

Answer (score 0):

you could use the my.settings .
make a settings called Difficulty

[image]

And on form load check what you stored there.

Like this .

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    If My.Settings.Difficulty = "Easy" Then
        RadioButton1.Checked = True

    ElseIf My.Settings.Difficulty = "Hard" Then
        RadioButton2.Checked = True

    ElseIf My.Settings.Difficulty = "Unreal" Then
        RadioButton3.Checked = True

    End If
End Sub


Private Sub RadioButton1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.MouseClick
    My.Settings.Difficulty = "Easy"
    RadioButton2.Checked = False
    RadioButton3.Checked = False
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.MouseClick
    My.Settings.Difficulty = "Hard"
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    RadioButton3.Checked = False
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton3_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RadioButton3.MouseClick
    My.Settings.Difficulty = "Unreal"
    RadioButton1.Checked = False
    RadioButton2.Checked = False
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```